# CentOS 7 Live CD?

Tags: centos

On [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QzbX8o7pSY) at 1.09 I see CentOS 7 Live CD which allows to start CentOS directly from CD without installing it.

How can I make such disk?

I've downloaded .iso file from official web site, burned it, but it only allows me to "Install CentOS", i can't run CentOS without installing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick a mirror in [the mirrors page](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/). It will show you an FTP folder.
Reading the README.txt in that folder, we see:

```
CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-GnomeLive.iso
CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-KdeLive.iso

  These images are Live images of CentOS 7. Depending on the name they use the
respective display manager. They are designed for testing purposes and
exploring the CentOS 7 environment. They will not modify the content of your 
hard disk, unless you choose to install CentOS 7 from within the Live
environment. Please be advised that you can not change the set of installed
packages in this case. This needs to be done within the installed system
using 'yum'.

CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-livecd.iso

This is like the GnomeLive image mentioned above, but without packages such
as libreoffice. This image is small enough to be burned on a CD.
```

So pick the iso or torrent file you want accordingly

Answer (score 4):

The mirrors no longer appear to have any live .iso files available anymore.
Found links to the gnome live files [here](https://linuxclub.cs.byu.edu/downloads/isos/centos/).